# Python - Tensor Flow Error, Tensor must be from the same graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a conv_net function defined in my data_split file like this,

```
def conv_net(X, weights, biases, dropout):
    X = tf.reshape(X, shape=[-1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, NETWORK_DEPTH])
#error occurs on the below line - while calling the function in debugging mode
    conv1 = conv2d('conv1', X, weights['conv_weight1'], biases['conv_bias1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d('max_pool1', conv1, k=2)

    conv2 = conv2d('conv2', conv1, weights['conv_weight2'], biases['conv_bias2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d('max_pool2', conv2, k=2)

    conv3 = conv2d('conv3', conv2, weights['conv_weight3'], biases['conv_bias3'])
    conv3 = maxpool2d('max_pool3', conv3, k=2)

    conv4 = conv2d('conv4', conv3, weights['conv_weight4'], biases['conv_bias4'])
    conv4 = maxpool2d('max_pool4', conv4, k=2)

    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv4, shape=[-1, weights['fcl_weight1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['fcl_weight1']), biases['fcl_bias1']))
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    fc2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['fcl_weight2']), biases['fcl_bias2']))
    fc2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc2, dropout)

    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc2, weights['out_weight']), biases['out_bias'], name='softmax')
    return out
```

And I am calling this function in another .py file like this,

```
print("Comp2")
logits = data_split.conv_net(data_split.X, data_split.weights, data_split.biases, keep_prob)
print("Comp2.0")
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

This is giving me an error when I am running the logits line.

> ValueError: Tensor("conv_weight1:0", shape=(5, 5, 4, 16), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Reshape_12:0", shape=(?, 100, 100, 4), dtype=float32).

I tried to get my answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527048/valueerror-tensor-must-be-from-the-same-graph-as-tensor) - but of no help.

Comment: You are not giving the full code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the `data_split.py` file or in the "other" `.py` file you have a `tf.Graph()` definition.

You defined the model in a graph, something like:

```
g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default():
    model = conv_net(data_split.X)
```

But the `data_split.X` you're passing the model has been defined outside the `g1` scope, hence or in the "default graph" (that you can get with `tf.get_default_graph()` or in another explicitly defined graph (in the same way as `g1`).

The solution is to move the input definition and the model definition inside the same graph (hint: in cases like this one, just use the default graph without creating explicitly a `tf.Graph').

Note: without sharing the complete code this is the best you can get.